# Extend existing module in symfony 1.4

Tags: plugins, symfony1, module, symfony-1.4, extend

I would like to know what is the best solution / approach to extend a symfony 1 module. More exactly, what I want to do is:

1. Create a base module "MUSIC"
2. Create a new module AS A PLUGIN (let's name it ARTIST), that extends MUSIC

For each plugin created I would like to generate admin modules if needed.

If I am not clear enough, please ask.

Comment: Why do you want to make it this way (Extend a module with a plugin)? The Plugin would never work without the module, thats not how a plugins should work.

Comment: I actually need table inheritance. I read about at http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/09-Doctrine-Form-Inheritance and it's what i need. I like the idea to develop in API - like way, having a base engine and apply layers. This is why i want to use plugins. Or maybe just create an API application. I will think about. Thank you.